# Display available stack memory in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to display the consumed stack space during a recursive program execution, like inorder traversal of a tree. Is there a way to print the available stack space in Java, I know that available heap memory could be displayed using Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory().

Comment: What you mean by display? You want to grab threads/heap at the time? Do you want do this programaticaly (from running app) or manualy/scripting from outside the app? Give more details plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't give you access to this kind of information, for various reasons:

1. keeping track of that information might actually make some kinds of optimizations impossible
2. giving an exact number at a certain point might slow down the execution (due to a potentially necessary de-optimization).
3. the exact amount of available space left might vary over time (for example if stack space were dynamically allocated from a shared space and not fixed).
4. Any value you might get is very likely to only be of limited value (as you can't know for sure how many bytes a given method invocation needs in various scenarios).

The *closest* you can get is to get a current stack trace (for example using [`Thread.getStackTrace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace())) and check the returned arrays size to know how many stack *frames* are in use (i.e. how deep the stack already is).

But even that operation is likely to be somewhat costly.

Comment: Perhaps the [`StackWalker`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.html) API could be used to reduce the cost a bit (could at least avoid materializing the array).

Comment: @Hulk: it's quite possible that this allows for a slightly reduced cost. But the issue is that the act of getting a stack trace at all makes some optimizations (inlining for example) much harder/more expensive. So even if this improves performance, I don't think it will fully remove the drawbacks.

Comment: Agreed. Either method for determining the stack depth will allocate several objects (and involve multiple levels of method calls).